# How do I sync contents of my iPhone App with iPad using iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

I have iPad and iPod, both on iOS 5 with iCloud enabled.

I have an app which I have installed on both these devices.
With this app, I create some files, which I can see in Documents folder of iTunes.

How do I sync these files of that app in both devices using iCloud?

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Does Settings have any iCloud-specific settings?  Maybe you need to enable this feature for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your *app* (no details provided) needs to support iCloud in order to sync files between devices.

Comment: Of course, that app does support iCloud.

Comment: @meetpd If the app supports iCloud and it still does not sync files between devices, contact the developers of the app for support. BTW, what app is it?